# Scan debit card number using card.io

Tags: android, card.io

I am using card.io for scanning credit card and debit card. I got to know that if number is embossed then only it will scan card. So i just want to know is it possible to use openCv or any other technique to read debit card (where number is not embossed) with same accuracy as card.io providing now

Comment: Hi, Did you find any solution related to this question?

Comment: No i could not. :(

Comment: I got a whole load of flak for asking this question here.. did you ever find another library?

Comment: @Saik Caskey Nope. Still no luck